# Poetry: changing to private pypi repository on the command line

Tags: python, python-poetry

Locally, we use a private source URL for our poetry configurations, and the credentials will be found in our `pip.ini`. However, in our CI/CD pipeline we obtain a secret which changes the `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL`. This is not enough, because we need to change the `pyproject.toml` (see below) with this URL.

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "private"
url = "https://someplace.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/somewhere/pypi/simple/"
secondary = true
```

This is not changed with `poetry config repositories.private "$PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL"`. How should we change this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just the link without the credentials and specify the login like this:

```
poetry config repositories.someplace https://someplace.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/somewhere/pypi/
poetry config http-basic.someplace someuser $(personal-access-token)
```